# Update message in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: updates, kubuntu

In the Kubuntu KDE update program "Entdecken" (discover?), when new updates are available, there is a general description of the program but i cannot find the update message, showing what the update fixes. Where can i find it?

Comment: Install synaptic : `sudo apt-get install synaptic` ... and open `synaptic` , click the button "Mark All Upgrades" , and you get a list of all the packages with an update.

Comment: @ cucujoida: Do you mean something like the "changelog" of the package in question?

Comment: @ellisistfroh: exactly. How can i change the default discover updater to plasma-discover-updater?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the plasma-discover-updater (german:Aktualisierungsverwaltung) it is enough to tick on the package-name in the list, then the "changelog" of the package appears in a given field.

Comment: How can i switch from the default discover updater to plasma-discover-updater and set the latter as the default?

Answer (score 1):

@cucujoida,

The old muon-updater has been superceded by plasma-discover-updater. If you ensure that plasma-discover-updater has been installed, you can uninstall muon-updater if you still find that in your system.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Valorie, plasma-discover starts for updates, plasma-discover-updater remains unused by automatic updates. Therefore, the changelog of the updates is invisible.